# @Types/node/index.d.ts TypeScript Error TS2309

Tags: angular, typescript, types, npm, asp.net-core

I have a .Net Core Angular 2 project using SystemJs that I have recently upgraded from Typings to @Types.

The project has been completely rebuilt with the latest VS tooling for .Net Core 1.0.1 and TypeScript 2.0.10 and Node.js 7.0.0 as of 12/21/2016.

The project files were working properly before updating to @Types.

I am getting the following Error from @Types/node/index.d.ts:

TS2309 "Build:An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements." Line 3626

Line 3626 of @Types/node/index.d.ts is the Export for the "assert" module declaration.

Here are me config files

tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "removeComments": false,
  "noImplicitAny": false,
  "skipLibCheck": true
},
"compileOnSave": true,
"exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "wwwroot/shared/lib"
]
```

Package.json

```
"name": "angular-quickstart",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
"scripts": {
  "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
  "lite": "lite-server",
  "tsc": "tsc",
  "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "~2.2.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "~2.2.0",
  "@angular/core": "~2.2.0",
  "@angular/forms": "~2.2.0",
  "@angular/http": "~2.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.0",
  "@angular/router": "~3.2.0",
  "@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.0",
  "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.15",

  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
  "systemjs": "0.19.41",
  "zone.js": "^0.6.26",

  "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^0.6.1",
  "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^0.9.0",
  "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^0.16.10",
  "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^0.13.1",
  "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^0.15.0",
  "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^0.12.2",
  "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^0.10.4",
  "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^0.13.3",
  "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^0.13.2",
  "@progress/kendo-angular-scrollview": "^0.5.1",
  "@progress/kendo-angular-sortable": "^0.5.1",
  "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^0.1.6",
  "@telerik/kendo-theme-default": "^1.28.1",

  "jquery": "2.1.1",
  "jquery-validation": "1.15.1",
  "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.6",
  "office-ui-fabric-core": "5.0.1",
  "bootstrap": "3.3.7"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
  "@types/node": "^6.0.49",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
  "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
  "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
  "typescript": "^2.0.10",
  "gulp": "3.9.1",
  "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
  "gulp-concat": "2.6.0",
  "gulp-uglify": "2.0.0",
  "gulp-clean": "0.3.2",
  "gulp-typescript": "2.14.1"
},
"repository": {}
}
```

Comment: Is there a typings.json file in your project and a typings folder or have you changed or removed these?

Comment: I recreated the project without installing Typings, so there is no Typings folder or typings.json file. In the original project where Typings was installed, I did try to remove the files to avoid duplicates and I ended up with the same error TS2309, which promped me to start over from scratch just to make sure. I am not receiving any "Duplicate Identifier" errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion from TypeScript guys on GitHub fixed for us.

Do a search for the following -

```
declare module "assert" {
```

It should only appear once in your project.  We had it in two files - the TypeScript definition file in @types/node package and a 2nd one in our wwwroot folder which needed deleting and had been copied over in error by a Gulp task and was getting picked up by the compiler.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Sure enough, reflect-metadata contains a typings folder with a node.d.ts file that declares "assert". I can't delete the file because the compiler complains that it can't find it, but commenting out the declaration fixed the issue and the project is error free again. Thank you!