# TypeScript Compilation Failure After Upgrade to 2.0

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have an Angular 2.2.0 project in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 TS V 2.  Everything was compiling and working perfectly until I installed the latest version of TypeScript 2.0 (First time I installed it corrupted my VS and had to do a full re-install).  Now literally getting 1000s of errors.  Spent several days and have no idea what's happened.

Screenshot below shows the errors I'm getting.  Most/all seem to be from TS files in my node_modules directory but these are specifically excluding in my TSConfig so no idea what is going on.  VS, NPM, Angular2 & TS is probably one of the most painfull development experiences I have encountered in my career so difficult to get everything set up and running correctly and staying that way.  Any help would be hugely appreciated.

[Visual studio errors since upgrade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUD6Y.png)

Comment: What d.ts's you have in your typings folder? After 2.0 If I remember correctly 2 folders got these conflicts.

Comment: haha, welcome to the JavaScript world. I think you are transpiling to es6, try setting es5 in your tsconfig.json

Comment: As the errors suggest the typescript compiler finds certain definitions more that once and he doesn't like that (who would?). If you are using typings make sure you clean up and reinstall just the required ones and best to upgrade to @types. Give some more info on what you are using for definitions and we might be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks for comments.  Tsconfig is set to es5 going to try and uninstall my typings this may be where the problem is as it was set up using an Angular quickstart for VS a while back.

Comment: OK now having the same problem as this guy [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725540/types-node-index-d-ts-typescript-error-ts2309).  Removed typings refrences exactly as he did, from the TS2 release notes we should have had backwards compatibility with typings and everything should have woked.  This surely can't be the future of web development!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve we deleted all reference and use of typings and instead moved to @types imports.  Also ensure you totally clear out any TS definition files that may have been copied over to wwwroot folders that you may be unaware of.